# Cannot find a way to execute getBotCommands method

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

According to docs there is a command `getBotCommands` - https://core.telegram.org/method/bots.getBotCommands

However none of my request work:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/getBotCommands
```

returns `{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}`

The same request to `sendmessage` endpoint at least returns `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message text is empty"}⏎` so I understand that such endpoint exists, however I cannot understand why am I getting such responses from `getBotCommands`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong documentation, your link is for the Telegram Core, you're looking for the [Telegram Bot Api Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

Here you will find info about the [`getMyCommands`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getmycommands) endpoint:

> ##### getMyCommands
>
> Use this method to get the current list of the bot's commands for the given scope and user language.
> Returns an Array of [BotCommand](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#botcommand) objects. If commands aren't set, an empty list is returned.

---

So the url becomes:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/getmycommands
```

Which returns something like the following:

```json
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "command": "foo",
            "description": "This is the Foo command"
        },
        {
            "command": "bar",
            "description": "Yea this is the Bar variant"
        }
    ]
}
```